# where errorElement appends in DOM in validation.js

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to  know where errorElement appends in DOM

```
enter code here

$("#Myform").validate({
errorClass:'error',
errorElement:'span',
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) 
{ 
    $(element).parents("div.control-group")
              .addClass(errorClass)
              .removeClass(validClass); 

}, 
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass)
{
    $(element).parents(".error")
              .removeClass(errorClass)
              .addClass(validClass); 
}
});



<form:form id="Myform">
<input id="Sname" type="text">
</form:form>
```

I want to know where my errorElement will append in the DOM.
Please tell, thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Default behavior is to be added right after the invalid element. It can be changed, just take a look at the documentation http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Answer (score 0):

```
        errorPlacement: function(error, element,label) {


        if ( element.is(":radio") )
            error.appendTo( element.parent().next().next() );
        else if ( element.is(":checkbox") )
            error.appendTo ( element.next().next().next());
        else{
        error.insertAfter(element); 


        if($.browser.msie){
        if(parseInt($.browser.version) =="7"){ element.parent().addClass("imgErrors");}

        }//browser check

     }
        error.appendTo( element.next() );
    }
```

This is the function that needs to be altered as per your convenience